# QHBoxLayout spacing changes when adding QWidget instead of QTextEdit

Tags: qt, alignment, qvboxlayout

I have the following code that gives me Lineedits (see picture):

```
QHBoxLayout *mainQHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout(); 
QWidget *trayQWidget = new QWidget();
trayQWidget->setLayout(mainQHBoxLayout);

ui.centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(trayQWidget);
for (int lauf = 10;lauf < 15;lauf++)
{
    QTextEdit *edit = new QTextEdit;
    edit->setText(QString("edit %1").arg(lauf));
    edit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    edit->setMaximumWidth(8 * lauf);
    edit->setMaximumHeight(7 * lauf);
    edit->setEnabled(false);
    edit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    edit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    edit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);     
    mainQHBoxLayout->addWidget(edit);
    mainQHBoxLayout->setAlignment(mainQHBoxLayout,Qt::AlignBottom);
}
mainQHBoxLayout->setSpacing(2);
mainQHBoxLayout->addStretch();
```

[image]

I am wondering why the Lineedits are not aligned to the bottom?

To achive the alignment i tried to add aditional QVBoxLayouts. Now the Allignemt ist OK but the spacing between the QlineEdits ist too big. (See picture)

```
QHBoxLayout *mainQHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout(); 
QWidget *trayQWidget = new QWidget();
trayQWidget->setLayout(mainQHBoxLayout);

ui.centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(trayQWidget);
for (int lauf = 10;lauf < 15;lauf++)
{
    QVBoxLayout *myQVBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QWidget *itemQWidget = new QWidget();
    itemQWidget->setLayout(myQVBoxLayout);
    myQVBoxLayout->addStretch();
    
    QTextEdit *edit = new QTextEdit;
    edit->setText(QString("edit %1").arg(lauf));
    edit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    edit->setMaximumWidth(8 * lauf);
    edit->setMaximumHeight(7 * lauf);
    edit->setEnabled(false);
    edit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    edit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    edit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);     
    myQVBoxLayout->addWidget(edit);
    mainQHBoxLayout->addWidget(itemQWidget);
}
mainQHBoxLayout->setSpacing(2);
mainQHBoxLayout->addStretch();
```

[image]

Has anybody an suggestion what could be my fault or what i could try next?

Framework is QT 5.6.1 Platform Windows10

Answer (score 1):

## First code snippet:

This line is wrong:

```
mainQHBoxLayout->setAlignment(mainQHBoxLayout,Qt::AlignBottom);
```

Does it not look strange to you to have `mainQHBoxLayout` used as the parameter of a method called upon **itself**, several times at that (once per loop since unlike `edit`, `mainQHBoxLayout` stays constant throughout your widget initialization)?
`setAlignment` is to align a **child** widget or a **child** layout in this fashion:

```
mainQHBoxLayout->setAlignment(edit, Qt::AlignBottom);
```

---

## Second code snippet:

A layout inside a widget has margins by default, therefore you need to get rid of them like so:

```
myQVBoxLayout->setContentsMargins(QMargins());
```

Better yet, get rid of `itemQWidget` and add each of your `myQVBoxLayout` generated in the loop as child layouts to your main layout. That way, no margins are created by default.

```
mainQHBoxLayout->addLayout(myQVBoxLayout);
```

---

The below code shows all 3 methods as reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextEdit>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    { //Correctly align  widgets
        QHBoxLayout* mainQHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        QWidget* trayQWidget = new QWidget();
        trayQWidget->setLayout(mainQHBoxLayout);

        for (int lauf = 10; lauf < 15; lauf++)
        {
            QTextEdit* edit = new QTextEdit;
            edit->setText(QString("Aligned widgets %1").arg(lauf));
            edit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
            edit->setMaximumWidth(8 * lauf);
            edit->setMaximumHeight(7 * lauf);
            edit->setEnabled(false);
            edit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
            edit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
            edit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
            mainQHBoxLayout->addWidget(edit);
            mainQHBoxLayout->setAlignment(edit, Qt::AlignBottom);
        }
        mainQHBoxLayout->setSpacing(2);
        mainQHBoxLayout->addStretch();
        trayQWidget->show();
    }

    { //Get rid of margins
        QHBoxLayout* mainQHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        QWidget* trayQWidget = new QWidget();
        trayQWidget->setLayout(mainQHBoxLayout);

        for (int lauf = 10; lauf < 15; lauf++)
        {
            QVBoxLayout* myQVBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
            myQVBoxLayout->setContentsMargins(QMargins());

            QWidget* itemQWidget = new QWidget();
            itemQWidget->setLayout(myQVBoxLayout);
            myQVBoxLayout->addStretch();

            QTextEdit* edit = new QTextEdit;
            edit->setText(QString("Widgets without margins %1").arg(lauf));
            edit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
            edit->setMaximumWidth(8 * lauf);
            edit->setMaximumHeight(7 * lauf);
            edit->setEnabled(false);
            edit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
            edit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
            edit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
            myQVBoxLayout->addWidget(edit);

            mainQHBoxLayout->addWidget(itemQWidget);
        }
        mainQHBoxLayout->setSpacing(2);
        mainQHBoxLayout->addStretch();

        trayQWidget->show();
    }

    { //Add layouts as child layouts
        QHBoxLayout* mainQHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        QWidget* trayQWidget = new QWidget();
        trayQWidget->setLayout(mainQHBoxLayout);

        for (int lauf = 10; lauf < 15; lauf++)
        {
            QVBoxLayout* myQVBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
            myQVBoxLayout->addStretch();

            QTextEdit* edit = new QTextEdit;
            edit->setText(QString("Child layouts %1").arg(lauf));
            edit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
            edit->setMaximumWidth(8 * lauf);
            edit->setMaximumHeight(7 * lauf);
            edit->setEnabled(false);
            edit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
            edit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
            edit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
            myQVBoxLayout->addWidget(edit);
            mainQHBoxLayout->addLayout(myQVBoxLayout);
        }
        mainQHBoxLayout->setSpacing(2);
        mainQHBoxLayout->addStretch();

        trayQWidget->show();
    }


    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. The 1st method was the one i was looking for. And yes i was wondering to have mainQHBoxLayout used as the parameter of a method called upon itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution ist to set the Margin of the myQVBoxLayout to "0"

```
myQVBoxLayout->setMargin(0);
```